# can I use Racket to write practical GUI program?

Tags: user-interface, racket

I want to use Racket to write code in Data-structure and Algorithm class. This class requires UI implementation, Does Racket have enough UI library to support it? Or I have to use common lisp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There are support for many GUI components.

The programming environment DrRacket is an example of an application using the Racket GUI libraries.

For a gallery and GUI elements:

```
http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Widget_Gallery.html?q=gui
```

Find snippets at Rosetta:

```
 http://rosettacode.org/wiki/GUI_component_interaction#Racket
```